# Find sum of the column values based on some other column

Tags: python-2.7

I have a input file like this:

```
j,z,b,bsy,afj,upz,343,13,ruhwd
u,i,a,dvp,ibt,dxv,154,00,adsif
t,a,a,jqj,dtd,yxq,540,49,kxthz
j,z,b,bsy,afj,upz,343,13,ruhwd
u,i,a,dvp,ibt,dxv,154,00,adsif
t,a,a,jqj,dtd,yxq,540,49,kxthz
c,u,g,nfk,ekh,trc,085,83,xppnl
```

1. For every unique value of **Column1**, I need to find out the sum of **column7**
2. Similarly, for every unique value of **Column2**, I need to find out the sum of **column7**

Output for 1 should be like:

```
j,686
u,308
t,98
c,83
```

Output for 2 should be like:

```
z,686
i,308
a,98
u,83
```

I am fairly new in Python. How can I achieve the above?

Comment: Looks like you add values from column 7 or column 8. Can you explain the rule you use.

Comment: Maybe `itertools.groupby` can be of some assistance. You will need some `sort` as a previous step, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done using Python's [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter) and [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) library as follows:

```
from collections import Counter
import csv

c1 = Counter()
c2 = Counter()

with open('input.csv') as f_input:
    for cols in csv.reader(f_input):
        col7 = int(cols[6])
        c1[cols[0]] += col7
        c2[cols[1]] += col7

print "Column 1"
for value, count in c1.iteritems():
    print '{},{}'.format(value, count)

print "\nColumn 2"

for value, count in c2.iteritems():
    print '{},{}'.format(value, count)
```

Giving you the following output:

```
Column 1
c,85
j,686
u,308
t,1080

Column 2
i,308
a,1080
z,686
u,85
```

A `Counter` is a type of Python dictionary that is useful for counting items automatically. `c1` holds all of the column 1 entries and `c2` holds all of the column 2 entries. Note, Python numbers lists starting from `0`, so the first entry in a list is `[0]`.

The `csv` library loads each line of the file into a list, with each entry in the list representing a different column. The code takes column 7 (i.e. `cols[6]`) and converts it into an integer, as all columns are held as strings. It is then added to the counter using either the column 1 or 2 value as the key. The result is two dictionaries holding the totaled counts for each key.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Evans.
Could you please tell me, what exactly is statement c1[cols[0]] += col7 doing?

Comment: For each row it is adding the current count to the corresponding column1 key in the Counter dictionary. I've have improved the explanation to hopefully make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv', header=None)
print(df.groupby(0)[6].sum())
print(df.groupby(1)[6].sum())
```

Output:

```
0
c      85
j     686
t    1080
u     308
Name: 6, dtype: int64
1
a    1080
i     308
u      85
z     686
Name: 6, dtype: int64
```

The data frame should look like this:

```
print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2    3    4    5    6   7      8
0  j  z  b  bsy  afj  upz  343  13  ruhwd
1  u  i  a  dvp  ibt  dxv  154   0  adsif
2  t  a  a  jqj  dtd  yxq  540  49  kxthz
3  j  z  b  bsy  afj  upz  343  13  ruhwd
4  u  i  a  dvp  ibt  dxv  154   0  adsif
```

You can also use your own names for the columns. Like `c1`, `c2`, ... `c9`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv', index_col=False, names=['c' + str(x) for x in range(1, 10)])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  c1 c2 c3   c4   c5   c6   c7  c8     c9
0  j  z  b  bsy  afj  upz  343  13  ruhwd
1  u  i  a  dvp  ibt  dxv  154   0  adsif
2  t  a  a  jqj  dtd  yxq  540  49  kxthz
3  j  z  b  bsy  afj  upz  343  13  ruhwd
4  u  i  a  dvp  ibt  dxv  154   0  adsif
5  t  a  a  jqj  dtd  yxq  540  49  kxthz
6  c  u  g  nfk  ekh  trc   85  83  xppnl
```

Now, group by column 1 `c1` or column `c2` and sum up column 7 `c7`:

```
print(df.groupby(['c1'])['c7'].sum())
print(df.groupby(['c2'])['c7'].sum())
```

Output:

```
c1
c      85
j     686
t    1080
u     308
Name: c7, dtype: int64
c2
a    1080
i     308
u      85
z     686
Name: c7, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hi Mike,
Your code gives me the below error:
KeyError: 'no item named 0'

Comment: Hi Mayank. Do you have empty lines at beginning of your file? Check how `df` looks like. See my edited answer above.

Comment: Hi Mike. No empty lines are there in the file. I've pasted my output just below your output. 

As per what I read in the panda docs, we have to put column name in the groupby clause. Can you please explain what exactly does 0 and 6 represent in your groupby statement?
print(df.groupby(0)[6].sum())

Comment: The numbers are the column names. I added an example with string column names `c1` ... `c9`. Try if this works better.

Comment: Thanks Mike.
When I am trying to run the below:
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv', index_col=False, names=['c' + str(x) for x in range(1, 10)])

It fails saying this:
raise Exception('Index has duplicates: %s' % str(dups))
Exception: Index has duplicates: ['j', 't', 'u']

Comment: What pandas version are using? `pd.__version__`

Comment: That is too old. I use version 0.17.1. Please update.

Comment: Hi Mike..
I've updated the version of pandas and everything works fine.
Now, in the Output you pasted, the column in which the calculation of column appears, can I have it with a string(ex: "may":85,"may":686)?

Answer (score 0):

SO isn't supposed to be a code writing service, but I had a few minutes. :) Without Pandas you can do it with the CSV module;

```
import csv

def sum_to(results, key, add_value):
    if key not in results:
        results[key] = 0

    results[key] += int(add_value)


column1_results = {}
column2_results = {}

with open("input.csv", 'rt') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        sum_to(column1_results, row[0], row[6])
        sum_to(column2_results, row[1], row[6])


print column1_results
print column2_results
```

Results:

```
{'c': 85, 'j': 686, 'u': 308, 't': 1080}
{'i': 308, 'a': 1080, 'z': 686, 'u': 85}
```

Your expected results don't seem to match the math that Mike's answer and mine got using your spec. I'd double check that.